# Excel VBA - Loop through each row, find "Pending" status then copy and paste into other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am not very good at VBA but I am trying to learn. I have researched this question before posting for almost 4 days and I have found responses that were close to what I need but was not able to tailor it to my needs. So, I am using this as a last resort.

I have a report that I pull from an online application that downloads to a CSV file. It will always have columns from A:DA but have a varying set of rows. The first 5 columns are for A: Employee Name, B: Record ID, C: Client First Name, D: Client Last Name, E: Date of Birth. The rest of the columns are in groups of 5 that repeat until column DA. So for example, F: Provider #, G: Office Name, H: Date of Appt, I: Time of Appt, J: Status of Appt. Then those 5 columns are repeated until column DA.

So basically, each row is a record of an employee, a client, and all of the client's appointment history. F:J would be their first appointment, K:O is their second appointment, P:T their third, and so on all the way to DA.

What I need is some code that will check each row for a "Pending" Status of Appt, copy that appointment (all 5 cells) and the very first 5 cells (A:E), and paste them into another worksheet called "Output" so that I will end up with a list of only the clients with pending appointments (the source data is on a sheet called "Input" by the way).

One issue is that clients may have more than one "Pending" appointment in their record. So the code cannot stop at the first "Pending" appointment it finds and then go to the next record. It would have to look through the entire row before moving to the next.

I know that this is probably a simple problem for you experts but I am about ready to walk into oncoming traffic over this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward VBA learning exercise. You just need two loops. Create a loop for every row of your data (for myrow=1 to lastrow). For each row, create another loop that repeats for each group of 5 cells. Check the Pending status and if it's true, copy/paste or assign the values in that group of 5 cells and A to E to your output sheet. Keep a counter for your new sheet row and add 1 to it every time you write a row.

Comment: Show us at least some code. Your question could be asked in 2 lines, not this whole page

Comment: i am sorry about the lengthy description but i have read many posts where the replies say they description was too vague so i tried to be as thorough as possible. and i dont have any code to show you because i have no idea how to write it. this is because i suck....carols suggestion kind of makes sense to me but again i have no idea how to do it. watching some youtube tutorials now...maybe ill figure it out in a day or two.....